# jQuery parse HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple function, that looks like this

```
var getCellText = function ($cell) {
  var html = $cell.html();
  $(html).find("input").each(function () {
    alert(this.value);
  });
}
```

The HTML could look like this

```
<input class="lineno" name="lineno" value="4109375" type="hidden">
<input onchange="Time.UpdateLine(this, 'studentno', this.value, '4109375');" class="studentno" value="2088" type="text">
```

I need to get the value of the **studentno** input tag (and I can ignore the input called **lineno**).

How can I do that, as you can see, I have already given it a try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. Don't use `.html()`, do use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val).

```
function getCellText($cell)
{
    var value = $cell.find('input.studentno').val();
    console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `$cell` variable is a jQuery object containing a parent element of `.studentno`, this will work:

```
var getCellText = function ($cell) {
    alert($(".studentno", $cell).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('input.studentno',html).each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what you mean by get rid of the `.html()` bit.